# error sending request to the Action class from a href link in struts2

Tags: struts2

When i use this code to send request to the Action class from a link in struts2, it works fine.

```
<a href="<s:url action="link"/>">Add New Case</a>
```

struts.xml

```
<action name="link" class="casediary.JudicialCaseRegister" method="execute">
    <result name="clientlist">user.jsp?pageinclude=ancar</result>
    <result name="error">user.jsp?pageinclude=errancar</result>
</action>
```

But when i am using this link, i am getting **HTTP Status 404 - /Judicial/link** error.

```
<a href="link">Add New Case</a>
```

struts.xml remains the same both time.

How to do this, please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to force the `Action` execution like this:

```
<a href="link.action">Add New Case</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

for execution of the action, i used struts anchor tags

```
<s:a action="myAction">Click here</s:a>
```

and it works fine.